# Downloading file after selecting folder not directly to downloads folder in PHP

Tags: php

I got one piece of code that, when I press the download button, the file get saved in the Downloads folder in my PC. Instead of that, I want to have a folder selection dialog and then to saving that file to that folder in D drive or another drive. How can I do that?

```
if(file_exists($dms->contentDir . $content->getPath())) {
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($dms->contentDir . $content->getPath() ));
    $efilename = rawurlencode($content->getOriginalFileName());
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $efilename . "\"; filename*=UTF-8''".$efilename);
    header("Content-Type: " . $content->getMimeType());
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");

    readfile($dms->contentDir . $content->getPath());
}
```

Comment: That's a browser setting, you can't enforce it from the server.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible. This is part of the user settings in the browser. You cannot make a webpage force different settings.

The only thing you could do is hint a filename, as I see you are doing. But that does not mean it will not be changed by the user during/after download.

Comment: Yes...actaully i changed the downloads settings in browser .it works exactly what i want. just i thought any possible in doing in PHP script. anyway thank you.